# matplotlib subplot with dates: cannot change xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a subplot, plotting 3 time series over 2 different axes.
My time series go from Jan-2007 till Sep-2017 (one data point per month).

My problem is that I cannot change the limits of the x axis.

I have tried both xlim and set_xlim, but they have no effect whatsoever.

What am I doing wrong?

An example of my code is below.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import dateutil

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick

mystart = dt.date(2007,1,1)
mydates =[mystart]
for i in np.arange(1,130):
    mydates.append( mystart +dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta(months=i))

df=pd.DataFrame()
df['month']=mydates
df['a']= np.arange(1,131)
df['b']=df['a']/2
df['c']=0.25

fig,ax=plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].set_title('My title')
l1 = ax[0].plot_date( df['month'],df['a'], label= 'a (left axis)', color='blue', ls='solid', marker ='')
l2 = ax[0].plot_date( df['month'],df['b'], label= 'b (left axis)',color='red',  ls='solid', marker ='')

# THESE BELOW ARE THE TWO LINES I CANNOT GET TO WORK!!!

#plt.xlim(xmin= dt.date(2012,1,31),xmax=dt.date(2017,9,30))
ax[0].set_xlim([dt.date(2012,1,31),dt.date(2017,9,30)], auto=True)


ax[0].grid()

ax2=ax[0].twinx()
l3 = ax2.plot_date( df['month'],df['c']*100 , label= 'some % (right axis)', color='green',  ls='solid', marker ='')

fmt = '%.2f%%' # Format you want the ticks, e.g. '40%'
yticks = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yticks)

ls=l1+l2+l3
labs=[l.get_label() for l in ls]
ax[0].legend(ls, labs, loc='upper left')

ax[1].set_title('Something else will go here...')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I think you can find the answer to your question in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32100912/changing-the-xlim-by-date-in-matplotlib

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. The guy in that example was calling datetime instead of datetime.datetime() - I'm not. In my example I call dt.date() but I also tried with dt.datetime() and it doesn't make a difference. He was getting an error - I am not getting any errors, but the xlim doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the limits of the axes **after** you have created the twin axes and plotted to it.

```
ax2=ax[0].twinx()
l3 = ax2.plot_date( ... )

ax[0].set_xlim( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it: the issue is the secondary axis.

I must repeat set_xlim for ax2, as well:

```
ax2.set_xlim([dt.datetime(2012,1,31),dt.datetime(2017,9,30)], auto=True)
```

I am not sure if this is a bug, TBH. I would have expected that creating a twin axis would have replicated the same xlim.